# How to decide lifetime annotations in circumstances like this?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a transaction database. The `Transaction` struct holds a reference to a `MutexGuard` which needs a lifetime annotation, so I have to put a lifetime annotation on the transaction struct. The transaction also has a reference count to the environment struct:

```rust
struct Transaction<'a> {
    mutex_guard: MutexGuard<'a, i32>,
    env: Arc<Env> //I don't know which lifetime annotation to use here for Env.
}
```

I want the environment to have a weak reference to the write transaction:

```rust
struct Env<'a> {
    w_txn: Weak<Transaction<'a>>
}
```

I have to put a lifetime annotation on the `Env` struct, which means the environment can't outlive  `w_txn`, but that's not what I want. I want the environment to always live longer than the transaction, that's why I use `Weak`.

So what should I do?

A minimal reproducible example:

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, MutexGuard, Weak};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Env<'a> {
    w_txn: Option<Weak<Txn<'a>>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Txn<'a> {
    env: Arc<Env<'a>>,
    mutex_guard: MutexGuard<'a, i32>,
}

impl Txn<'_> {
    fn new(env: Arc<Env>, mutex: &Mutex<i32>) -> Arc<Self> {
        Arc::new(Self {
            env: env.clone(),
            mutex_guard: mutex.lock().unwrap(),
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut env = Arc::new(Env { w_txn: None });
    let mut mutex = Mutex::new(0);
    let mut txn = Txn::new(env, &mutex);
    env.w_txn = Some(Arc::downgrade(&txn));
    println!("env: {:?}", env);
    println!("txn: {:?}", txn);
}
```

Comment: Is `MutexGuard` obtained from a `std::sync::Mutex` here?

Comment: Re: "I have to put a lifetime annotation in Env struct signature, which means the environment can't outlive the `w_txn`" - you don't need lifetimes to make a struct not outlive its contents; that's impossible. I think you misunderstand the `'a` parameter. What code are you trying to write that doesn't compile? Can you create a [mre]?

Comment: I just add a minimal reproducible example, the compiler says "cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements".

Comment: See also [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423)

Answer (score 2):

This appears to fix the lifetime issues:

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, MutexGuard, Weak};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Env<'a> {
    w_txn: Option<Weak<Txn<'a>>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Txn<'a> {
    env: Arc<Env<'a>>,
    mutex_guard: MutexGuard<'a, i32>,
}

impl<'a> Txn<'a> {
    fn new(env: Arc<Env<'a>>, mutex: &'a Mutex<i32>) -> Arc<Self> {
        Arc::new(Self {
            env: env.clone(),
            mutex_guard: mutex.lock().unwrap(),
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut env = Arc::new(Env { w_txn: None });
    let mut mutex = Mutex::new(0);
    let mut txn = Txn::new(env, &mutex);
    env.w_txn = Some(Arc::downgrade(&txn));
    println!("env: {:?}", env);
    println!("txn: {:?}", txn);
}
```

However it will still not compile for various other reasons. The code looks like it needs a redesign to be honest. The stuff you are trying to do does not work well with Rust and in my experience that's a fairly big red flag that the design in general is not a good one.

Comment: [Here is a playground that works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ed49a469eb3551cc282f5d40af13d6fb) by adding mutex around `Env::w_txn`, but I agree with you that this is probably a bad design.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I can't put all things to do in one function, so I have to hold the MutexGuard, to hold the MutexGuard, I have to use a lifetime annotation. I can't think of a better idea.

Comment: To assign the write mutex reference in Env, I choose to convert env into a raw pointer to do that, though it breaks rust rules. But I have mutex to make sure that only one thread is modifying the field.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it's difficult to explain what the problem is exactly, but I am quite confident you don't want a lifetime on that `Env` struct. Putting a lifetime on `Env` will have the compiler ensure that the `Env` struct itself lives for a shorter duration than the lifetime (that's what it means for a lifetime to be annotated on a type), but the lifetime is the duration in which you locked the mutex, and I'm pretty sure you intended for the `Env` struct to be longer-lived than the mutex guard.

Putting the mutex guard into the `Env` struct is not going to be possible, at least not if your mutex has a lifetime annotated on it. For example, the Tokio mutex has an `OwnedMutexGuard` that doesn't have any lifetimes annotated on it because it is based on reference counting instead of lifetimes, but it is an async lock, and therefore not really appropriate for your example — unfortunately, I'm not aware of any crate that provides a non-async mutex with this feature.

Perhaps you could restructure your code so that the mutex guard would not be accessible from the `Env` struct?

Answer (score 0):

After my exploration, I already found a solution.

```rust
use std::sync::{Mutex, MutexGuard, Arc, Weak};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Env<'a> {
    mutex: Mutex<i32>,
    txn: Option<Weak<Txn<'a>>>
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Txn<'a> {
    mutex_guard: Option<MutexGuard<'a, i32>>,
    env: Arc<Env<'a>>
}

impl Env<'_> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            mutex: Mutex::new(0),
            txn: None
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Txn<'a> {
    fn new(env: &'a Arc<Env<'a>>) -> Self {
        Self {
            mutex_guard: Some(env.mutex.lock().unwrap()),
            env: env.clone()
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut env = Arc::new(Env::new());
    println!("create env");
    {
        let txn = Arc::new(Txn::new(&env));
        println!("create txn");
        //env.txn = Some(Arc::downgrade(&txn));
        //assert!(env.mutex.lock().is_err());
        println!("{:?}", txn);
        println!("{:?}", env);
        println!("{:?}", env.mutex.try_lock());
    }

    //assert!(env.mutex.lock().is_ok());
    println!("{:?}", env.mutex.try_lock());
}
```

Comment: Note that this solution doesn't actually put a `MutexGuard` inside the environment, so the lifetime just becomes `'static`.